# How to get Typescript to compile custom GraphQL Scalars

Tags: typescript, graphql

This very simple GraphQL Custom Scalar fails with the typescript error:

TS2351: This expression is not constructable.
Type 'typeof import(".../graphql/node_modules/graphql/index")' has no construct signatures.

```
import GraphQLScalarType, { GraphQLInt } from 'graphql';

export const CustomScalar = new GraphQLScalarType({
    ...GraphQLInt,
    name: "CustomScalar"
})
```

what needs to be changed to get Typescript to compile it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to describe the problem you're having or question you're asking. Your current title is the useless repeating of the tag information (which shouldn't be in the title at all in most cases) with *and Scalers* as the only other words. Your title should be clear and descriptive enough that a future site user who is skimming a list of search results will know that it contains. For suggestions on writing a good title, see [ask].

Comment: Any ideas on why it does not compile?

Comment: There should be a second part of this error that points to a variable that *has no construct signatures* - please include the full error message.

Comment: link to github with typescript config added

Answer (score 1):

The problem is to do with how types are defined in graphql. This works fine:

```
import * as graphql from 'graphql';

export const CustomScalar = new graphql.GraphQLScalarType({
    ...graphql.GraphQLInt,
    name: "CustomScalar"
});
```